# Password protected app / login screen

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, protected

I built an iOS app and I want to have some kind of login screen so only those who know the password would be able to use it.

It doesn't actually have to have both username and password. Only a special code would be enough (a password). This password will be typed once right after the app is installed and the user will not need to type every time they open the app.

What is the best practise to do this?

Comment: you mean your login screen will have only one field for password? So, the app doesn't have username and pass and just one field for a pass or what? can you be more precise?

Comment: @O.Daniel Yes, that is right. One single field. If the password is typed correctly it will go to the next screen. The pass will be the same code for all. Never dealt with login in IOS.. Thank you.

Comment: but how will you check whether pass is right or not? With server side?

Comment: @O.Daniel I am looking for the easiest and simplest way at the moment. As long as it is secure. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

When in first user type the password , you can store it in keychain with app bundle key and read it in every open of the app to check if it's exists (user exists navigate to main screen) or nil (show login screen)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to just use one text field, it doesn't really matter if it is secure or not, whatever suits you best.

Once the user has entered the code correctly you can just store a bool in the UserDefaults to say that the user has logged in:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "UserLogged")
```

This bool is the one you will check every time the app is open to know whether to show the login or not.
This check could be done in the AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "UserLogged") == false {
        showLogin()
   } else {
        showMainScreen()
   }

   return true
}
```

Hope this helps